# How can I remove the email option from a PDF?

Tags: pdf

When our site displays a PDF using the browser plug-in, is there a way to disable the options to Email the document and/or save a copy?

I looked at FileOpen.com, but couldn't find their pricing, and I'm wondering if there's a way to alter the document with Javascript or some other means.

Comment: No, there isn't. You'll need to explore options for securing your document once it's on the desktop to stop them from doing naughty things with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the browser plugin will not allow you to disable those options.

Answer (score 2):

if you display a document, the client will already have it on their disk—in browser cache for example

Comment: That's right. You can't stop someone from downloading a file if you've already exposed it to them in order to display it in the browser. Forget that it's a PDF, in your case, the problem is that it's just a regular downloadable file.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the document to an image and show it in a frame so you get scroll bars, but you lose a lot of the conveniences that pdf offers.  As others have already pointed out, if you're sending something to their browser they have a copy of it and can save it if they like.